# cannot transfer calls in inbound call from pstn with ucma 5.0

Tags: c#, lync, ivr, ucma, skype-for-business

I'm developing a custom IVR system based on skype for buisienss and UCMA 5.0

In my application I'm using the `begintransfer` method to transfer calls to users.
When I call internally from the Skype client, everything is ok and the call is routed correctly.
Inbound calls from a pstn gateway call are answered and begintransfer is executed without exception, but the call is not routed to the extension.

Here is my code:
[call.BeginTransfer()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeY3f.png)

I cannot use forward (instead of transfer) because forward works when the call is not yet established. I need to play a recording and make choices for incoming calls not forwarding without the IVR.

I think I'm missing something in the "_toneController_ToneReceived" event

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
public class IVR
{

    private static void _toneController_ToneReceived(object sender, ToneControllerEventArgs e)
        {

            number += getToneString(tone);

            if (number.Length == 3)
            {
                try
                {    
                    CallTransferOptions unattendedTransferOptions = new CallTransferOptions(CallTransferType.Unattended);

                    //  currentCall.BeginTransfer(number, unattendedTransferOptions, TransferCallBack, null);
                    //currentCall.BeginTransfer(number , null,null);//, EndEndpointEstablish, new object());

                    currentCall.BeginTransfer(
                                       number,
                                       new CallTransferOptions(CallTransferType.Attended),
                                       result =>
                                       {
                                           try
                                           {
                                               currentCall.EndTransfer(result);
                                           }
                                           catch (OperationFailureException ofe)
                                           {
                                               Logger_Call.log(string.Format("The recipient declined or did not answer the call:{0}",
                                                   ofe));
                                           }
                                           catch (RealTimeException rte)
                                           {
                                               Logger_Call.log(string.Format("Error transferring call:{0}", rte));
                                           }
                                       }, null);


                    Logger_Call.log(currentCall.OriginalDestinationUri + " ==> " + number);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger_Call.log(currentCall.OriginalDestinationUri + " ==ex==> " + ex.Message);
                }
            }

        }

    private void InitializeCallReceive(string applicationUri, string serverName, int serverPort, NetworkCredential credential)
    {
        try
        {
            Debugger.Launch();

            ClientPlatformSettings clientPlatformSettings;
            clientPlatformSettings = new ClientPlatformSettings("IVR.Server", SipTransportType.Tls);

            collaborationPlatform = new CollaborationPlatform(clientPlatformSettings);
            collaborationPlatform.EndStartup(collaborationPlatform.BeginStartup(null, null));

            UserEndpointSettings endpointSettings;

            endpointSettings = new UserEndpointSettings(applicationUri, serverName, serverPort);


            endpoint = new UserEndpoint(collaborationPlatform, endpointSettings);


            endpoint.Credential = credential;

            endpoint.RegisterForIncomingCall<AudioVideoCall>(AudioVideoCallReceived);

            endpoint.EndEstablish(endpoint.BeginEstablish(null, endpoint));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }


    private void AudioVideoCallReceived(object sender, CallReceivedEventArgs<AudioVideoCall> e)
    {
        currentCall = e.Call;

        currentCall.AudioVideoFlowConfigurationRequested += new EventHandler<AudioVideoFlowConfigurationRequestedEventArgs>(Call_AudioVideoFlowConfigurationRequested);


        currentCall.EndAccept(currentCall.BeginAccept(null, null));

    }
    private void Call_AudioVideoFlowConfigurationRequested(object sender, AudioVideoFlowConfigurationRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        currentCall.Flow.StateChanged += new EventHandler<MediaFlowStateChangedEventArgs>(Flow_StateChanged);
    }
    private void Flow_StateChanged(object sender, MediaFlowStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _flow = (AudioVideoFlow)sender;

        if (e.State == MediaFlowState.Active)
        {
            try
            {
                ToneController _toneController = new ToneController();
                _toneController.ToneReceived += _toneController_ToneReceived;
                _toneController.AttachFlow(_flow);

                MediaSource source = new WmaFileSource("rec.wma");
                source.EndPrepareSource(source.BeginPrepareSource(MediaSourceOpenMode.Buffered, null, null));
                Player _player = new Player();
                _player.SetSource(source);

                _player.AttachFlow(_flow);
                _player.SetMode(PlayerMode.Automatic);

                _player.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
    }





}
```

Comment: please edit your code into your question instead of using an image of code

Comment: @KevinL codes added.

Answer (score 0):

the code is correct.
i had a wrong settings in skype server.
for transfer is working, **refer suport** must be enabled in trunk configuration.

check this link : 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2506083

> important note :
>
> The Lync Server Global, Site, or Pool Trunk Configuration policy has the Enable refer support option enabled
>
> The IP gateway that is deployed locally or the IP gateway that is deployed by the Internet Service Provider’s (ISP) SIP trunk service does not support the use of the SIP REFER method

**[image of trunk configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFlOB.png)**